# Unity framework for SwiftUI "Oddly Stepping" error in iOS 16.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, swiftui

I am using Unity as a library for SwiftUI quite a while now. However when updating to the newest iOS version (16.1) it stopped working. Compiling runs without a problem but during runtime I get an error when Unity is starting:
[image]

in:
[image]

I even started a completely new project with Unity included to SwiftUI and get the same error. As this is some kind of assembler code and I certainly do not know how to read it I don't really know where I have to start searching.

In the console I get: "warning: UnityFramework was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available." I tried several ways to turn off optimization as described in related questions which did not work. When unchecking "Debug" in the scheme options the project starts normally

Answer (score 1):

A similar thing happened to me. I'm not entirely sure if it's the same problem but in the console, I got a message saying UnityFramework is running optimized and may behave oddly. Unfortunately, I've tried a couple of ways to disable optimization but I've yet to find a solution.

For now, I'm able to bypass this error by disabling the debugger entirely. In order to do this, you have to go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and uncheck debug executable.

I'm not sure if this will work for you but I figured it'd be worth a shot!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can at least continue development now! However this problem should be resolved!